# A Poisson Process occurring before an event

Tags: probability, poisson-process

The Geophysics building at the University of Northern California is scheduled to be seismically reinforced. The reinforcement will occur at a random time uniformly distributed in the next $3$ years. Suppose that during any fixed time interval of length $t$, the number of major earthquakes is Poisson with mean $\lambda t$. Find the probability that no major earthquake occurs of the Geophysics building.

In a Poisson Process the probability that no event occurs within a period of time $t$ is $P_0(t) = e^{-\lambda t}$. I'm tempted to say that because the probability density function of the reinforcement occurring is $\frac13$ I can multiply this function by $P_0(t)$ and integrate from $0$ to $3$.  But I'm having trouble making this procedure rigorous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plan will work. This is the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Continuous_case): for an event $A$ and a continuous random variable $X$,
$$
   \Pr[A] = \int \Pr[A\mid X=x] f_X(x)\,dx.
$$
In this case, if we let $A$ be the probability of no earthquakes, and let $X$ be the number of years the building stays unreinforced, then $f_X(x)$ is $\frac13$ on $[0,3]$, and $\Pr[A \mid X=x] = e^{-\lambda x}$: the probability that in a time interval of length $x$, no events in the Poisson process will occur. The integral becomes
$$
    \Pr[A] = \int_0^3 \frac13e^{-\lambda x}\,dx.
$$